# Needing to send a post using AJAX and receive the POST on the other page

Tags: php, ajax, post

I had this working before but I must have changed something and not actually sure what I changed because the code looks fine to me but hey, from other peoples perspectives, it will be easier to spot the issue.

I am trying to edit the information in my table that's connected to my table. The information is editable when they click the text in that row. When they click anywhere outside the text area, it executes the command and goes to my other file that receives any Posts send my the first primary page.

Here is my code :

***Main Index page (AJAX)***

```
        function showEdit(editableObj) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
        } 

        function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
            $.ajax({
                url: "includes/saveedit_members.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                    window.location.replace("admin_members.php");
                }        
           });
        }
```

***Main Index page (HTML)***

```
<tbody>

<?php
foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
?>
<tr class="table-row" style="text-align: left;" id="no_enter">
<td style="font-size: 11px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>"></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'username','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["username"] != '' ? $faq[$k]["username"] : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'email','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["email"] != '' ? $faq[$k]["email"] : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'cpukey','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["cpukey"] != '' ? $faq[$k]["cpukey"] : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'ip','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["ip"] != '' ? $faq[$k]["ip"] : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'time','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["time"] != '' ? $faq[$k]["time"] : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'enabled','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["enabled"]  == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'activ_status','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["activ_status"]  == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="false" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'profile_picture','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["profile_picture"] != '' ? '<img src="'.$faq[$k]["profile_picture"].'" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">' : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'userLevel','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo ($faq[$k]["userLevel"] == 1 ? '<img src="images/member_rank.png" style="height: 18px; width: 18px;" > Member' : ($faq[$k]["userLevel"] == 2 ? '<img src="images/staff_rank.png" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;"> Staff' : ($faq[$k]["userLevel"] == 3 ? '<img src="images/admin_rank.png" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;"> Admin' : 'Unknown'))) ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="false" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'register_time','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["register_time"] != '' ? $faq[$k]["register_time"] : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'account_credits','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["account_credits"] != '' ? number_format($faq[$k]["account_credits"], 2, '.', '') : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'free_gifted_credits','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo number_format($faq[$k]["free_gifted_credits"], 2, '.', '') != '' ? number_format($faq[$k]["free_gifted_credits"], 2, '.', '') : 'None'; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

</tbody>
```

***Then for my page that receives the code (saveedit_members.php)***

```
<?php

if(!isset($POST['column']) || $_POST["editval"] || $_POST["id"]) {
    header('Location: error-pages/index.php');
} else if(isset($POST['column']) & $_POST["editval"] & $_POST["id"]) {
    include_once('../configuration/db.php');
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);
}
```

?>

**Any help will be MUCH appreciated  !**

Comment: Are your really storing unsanitized POST data directly in your database? That is medieval.

Comment: yes. What do you mean ?

Comment: What Problem You Are Facing?

Comment: `$POST['column']` should be `$_POST['column']`

Comment: @NanaPartykar My page just reloads and does nothing. Normally it would update the database with the new edited information. But this just refresh the page with the same information before it was edited.

Comment: @SameerK oh yea thanks. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Change

```
if(!isset($POST['column']) || $_POST["editval"] || $_POST["id"]) {
```

To

```
if(!isset($_POST['column']) || !isset($_POST["editval"]) || !isset($_POST["id"])) {
```

**2)** Change

```
else if(isset($POST['column']) & $_POST["editval"] & $_POST["id"]) {
```

To

```
else if(isset($_POST['column']) && isset($_POST["editval"]) && isset($_POST["id"])) {
```

**Updated Code**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['column']) || !isset($_POST["editval"]) || !isset($_POST["id"])) {
    header('Location: error-pages/index.php');
} else if(isset($_POST['column']) && isset($_POST["editval"]) && isset($_POST["id"])) {
    include_once('../configuration/db.php');
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: If It Helped. Then, Please Don't Forget To Mark This Answer As Correct Answer. As, It Will Help Other User's To Find This Answer Easily. *Keep Coding* @BenZa. If you don't know how to mark answer. Please go through this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work